# Underscore's pick method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, underscore.js

I'd like to use something like

```
hash.pick('prop1', 'prop2')
```

the same way as using underscores pick method ( takes properties of an object/hash and create a new hash based on them )

So it will look like this

```
{ prop1: 'asdf', prop2: 'qwer', prop3: 'uiop' }.pick( 'prop2', 'prop3' )
# equals { prop2: 'qwer', prop3: 'uiop' }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Ruby 2.5 and later, use the built-in hash.slice method.

```
{ prop1: 'asdf', prop2: 'qwer', prop3: 'uiop' }.slice(:prop2, :prop3)
```

This method was first introduced in Rails (ActiveSupport), so it was usable in earlier Ruby versions within Rails environment.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Hash slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) method as in:

```
hash.slice(:prop1, :prop2)
```